# How do I reset the USB port using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, usb

I use Macintosh. What I want to do is write a script that when I have a USB plugged in, to "Export" the USB, but then re-import it (as If I had physically taken the USB out and plugged it back in). Aka Unmountin the USB.

Most of my background is in writing code for galaxy simulations analyzing data, I have know idea how to go about something like this. I've been doing a lot of Googling and searching here, but can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: By "Export", do you  mean un-mount?

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you.